# Block 1 phone number in skype?

Tags: mac, skype

How can I block a single phone number from calling me in Skype? Under privacy I can block anyone not in my contacts but that isnt what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on a mac laptop, OS 10.7.5 with skype 6.8.0.351

The first thing you need to know is that to block someone, you first need to add them to your list of users. Yes, this feels nasty, and it's stupid. But you have to start there. OK, now that they're on your list, you can block them. Here's how.

step 1: open your main skype window. You will see your contacts either a list view or, if your default is like mine, you will see blue squares (or pictures) for each person. If you see blue squares, look for pair of little icons (mine are all the way in the upper right, past the "add contact" box.) They show two options: either 4 squares, or a bunch of horizontal lines. Click the horizontal lines icon to get from the "blue squares/pictures" view into list view.

Step 2: now you are in list view. Scroll to the user you want to block. Click on the white part of the line for the user you want to block. If you do it right, that line will be highlighted, but the view won't change. If you click on the number, it will instead bring up the number to edit. If you click on the picture, it will instead offer to call the person. Don't panic, just use the back button and try again.

Step 3: that line is now highlighted. If you now click on "contacts," you will see that the option, "block contact" is now available. Click on that. You will get a box asking you to confirm.

Step 4 (optional) As an added bonus, you can also "report abuse" while you block. Offering sex, one time, is not automatically abusive, if it comes from someone you know, and it's not threatening, just not something you want. But if someone is stalking you or harassing you or threatening you, that would be a good use of the "report abuse" button.

I assume there is some way to do this from the "squares" view, as well as the list view, but I have not figured it out yet. Hope this helps.